# Uploading an image to chat clears existing reply

Tags: bug, chat, images, uploader

I could have sworn that this workflow used to work:

1. See someone post something
2. Decide that replying with an image is the best thing to do
3. Click on reply arrow, causing the text box to have `:1234567` in it.
4. Click upload image button, and upload image
5. Yay, now you've uploaded a cat picture, and used it as a reply to the post.

Now if I try this, the image doesn't end up as a reply - it's just out there, all on its own, and hovering over it doesn't highlight the message I wanted to reply to.

Either I'm going insane (which is totally possible), or this is a regression.

Comment: It never worked for me; I always quickly edit the message after uploading to insert the reply pointer.